# Highstock xAxis Plotband

Tags: javascript, highcharts, graphing

I am new to Highstock and would like to know how to highlight an x axxis plot band to a chart in highstock.

I have crafted a sample at:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2509207/PlotBand.html

Can someone show me how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

Use axis plotbands: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.plotBands (add when chart is created) or add them dynamically: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.addPlotBand()

Comment: This is for highcharts. I cannot find an implementation that works on highstock.